# VNA for antenna measurement

Tags: antenna

I'm trying to learn how to use a VNA to get the impedance and smith chart for a given antenna.  I'm working at 2.4Ghz do I just need a VNA that operates up to 3GHz or is there some reason that I need a higher input bandwidth?  I'm trying to play along with this article [here](http://www.antenna-theory.com/measurements/impedance.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use a device beyond the frequency you wish to measure - your antenna will have some usable bandwidth and it is useful to see beyond that to see the roll-off or other characteristics.  3 GHz is fine.

The VNA IF bandwidth is very low compared to the frequency it measures, btw.